# Deleting a git branch to remove sensitive information

Tags: git, github

A git branch was created and is no longer going to be merged. Somewhere down the line there was a commit that contained sensitive information that should not be in the repo, so an amend won't overwrite that. Will deleting the entire branch on github remove the info? Or should I take another course of action?

Comment: Follow the steps here to remove sensitive information : [link][1]


  [1]: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: Please search harder on SO for answers to this question, of which there are many.